# What is the best way working multiple projects with angular?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am working on Angular app which includes:

1. User app - domain.com
2. Company panel app - domain.com/company
3. Admin panel app - which can manage both - domain.com/admin

In the future - the user and company app will multiple to other versions (different DB and design) and the admin panel will need to manage them all.

What is the best way to play this? 
make each one as a project and after build upload them to one domain (can I do that?), or make multiple project in one app angular? (what are the advantage and disadvantage using those options)

Please help me see what I can't see, because I am confuse right now and don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to create subdomains and separate each angular app in different projects:

```
userapp.domain.com
company.domain.com
admin.domain.com
```

and build each app for specific domain.
when your project separate from each other you can manage them better and if you want to give your project to some one to work on it it's not necessary to give him all of the codes.